# ICC compile options for evaluating macros in GDB while debugging

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gdb, icc

I would like to evaluate and print the macro while debugging using GDB. While the GDB [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html) has steps to do that by compiling using -g3 flag in [gcc compiler](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Compilation.html#Compilation), I am using [Intel Icc compiler](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/oneapi-dpcpp-cpp-compiler-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/output-debug-and-precompiled-header-options/debug-linux.html). Their debugging compilation options seem to have no information about macros. Is it possible to do that using icc? If yes what are the compilation options.

Comment: If using the newer LLVM-based Intel compiler (ICX), you should be able to do that via `-g -fdebug-macro` — same option as Clang.

Comment: is `2021.3.0` LLVM-based?

Comment: I think 2021.3.0 release includes both `icc` (classic) and `icx` (llvm-based) compilers.

Comment: @amonakov post this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`icc --help` prints almost 2000 lines of output, among which there's

```
-debug [keyword]
          Control the emission of debug information.
          Valid [keyword] values:
[snip]
             [no]macros
                 Controls output of debug information for preprocessor macros.
```

but passing `-debug macros` results in an error:

```
icc: command line error: Unrecognized keyword 'macros' for option '-debug'
```

It's unclear what happened here, perhaps the option was available in the past, and removed since then. You can report this to Intel.

The new LLVM-based Intel compiler, ICX, can emit macro definitions to debug info under the same option as Clang, `-fdebug-macro`.